# NullPointerException in AbsSpinner.onMeasure:195, what could be the cause?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have an Android app out there in the market. It uses Flurry, and it reports these crashes relatively often. I could never reproduce it, and since there's no stack trace, I don't even have any idea what code triggers it. Is anyone familiar with this issue?

Update: 2 years later, I'm still getting this crash pretty often.